# Django Tables 2 limiting fields from form

Tags: python, django, django-tables2

I am trying to limit the fields to in my table. The only way I see to do it is through the PersonTable object with the field property like this fields = [first_name, last_name]. I want to do it from a request form. I tried to override the get_queryset() method but it did not work only passed in less data but the columns were still there just blank. Is there a good way to do it with the generic view?

```
class Person(models.Model): 
    first_name =models.CharField(max_length=200)
    last_name =models.CharField(max_length=200) 
    user = models.ForeignKey("auth.User") dob = models.DateField() 


class PersonTable(tables.Table): 
    class Meta: 
        model = Person
        fields = [first_name, last_name]


class PersonList(SingleTableView):
    model = Person
    table_class = PersonTable
```

Answer (score 0):

If anyone runs into this same issue, there is an exclude instance variable on the table class so you can just override get_table and do something like this in your view:

```
class PersonList(SingleTableView):
    model = Person
    table_class = PersonTable
    template_name = "person.html"

    def get_table(self):
        table = super(PersonList, self).get_table()
        columns = self.request.GET.getlist('column')
        tuple_to_exclude = tuple(set(table.columns.names()) - set(columns))
        table.exclude = tuple_to_exclude
        return table
```